# Making table for a dynamic dataframe w Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, charts

I am trying to make a table for better data visualization of my operations. I have checked out tabulate or prettytable, however they offer solutions for static table. I will give an example:

| Date | 05/02/2021 | 06/02/2021... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Glov (earnings) | 256 | 320 |
| XXX (earnings) | 258 | 220 |

The list of initiators (glov, xxx...) varies depending on the imported document. It is true that using groupby with pandas makes the output organised, however I would like it to be as a proper table. What do you suggest me to use?

Below is the class associated with the data calculations:

```
    def evaluate(self):
        user_start = pd.to_datetime(input("Enter your start date (yyyy.mm.dd hour:min:second): "))
        user_stop = pd.to_datetime(input("Enter your end date (yyyy.mm.dd hour:min:second): "))

        # creates series of True or False selecting proper rows.
        self.data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(self.data['Date'], dayfirst=True)
        self.mask = self.data['Date'].apply(self.in_range, args=(user_start, user_stop))

        print('')

    def evaluate_montant(self):
        montant_init = self.data.loc[self.mask].groupby("Initiateur")["Montant (centimes)"].sum()
        print(montant_init)
        print('')
```

```
output example:
Initiateur
 Glovoapp           380833
Avito                67800
Avito Mobile         64000
Careem Adyen         38400
Casaurba            312000
Showroomprive.ma    934740
Zara.ma              49900
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use tkinter, jinja, pyqt or bokeh, flask, etc. what's your output like? HTML base or gui for pc

Comment: gui for pc. thank you for the answer @kağan hazal koçdemir

Comment: okay then you have to use some gui module. i recommend pyqt6 or pyside2. all of them have a treeview module. If you want to keep it simple, you could do it with tkinter.

Comment: is it possible to adapt my py project to pyqt/ tkinter ?

Comment: of course. create a gui and show your data in it. for basic example : https://pythonguides.com/python-tkinter-treeview/